# what's the best way to generate an ember application?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, single-page-application, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I used yeoman's [generator-ember](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-ember) to setup my ember application. I see now that there's [ember-app-kit](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-app-kit) developed by an ember core team member.

Is there an advantage to using ember-app-kit over yeoman's ember generator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two do overlap when trying to start up an application. This [Github](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-ember/issues/102) issue is worth looking over as the Ember.js Yeoman generator maintainers discuss the current state of EAK and their Ember generator. Both EAP and generator share the Grunt and Bower toolset.

The Ember generator team is working towards making sure the two have a good future together.

EAK does have the blessing from the Ember Core team and includes ECMAScript 6 Modules, but maintainers for the Ember.js generator mentioned that they'll make a branch that uses Ember App Kit, he might provide a migration path. Worth subscribing to the issue and following along:

Here are the template layouts for both projects:

Ember App kit:

[image: Ember App Kit]

Ember generator:

[image: Ember generator]

**[Github Issue](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-ember/issues/102)**

From Addy Osmani:

> In the long-term we're working with Ryan (and Ember) to design a more robust generator system than what we have at present, perhaps building on top of one or two of the ideas he put into Ember-Tools. For the short-term, his project is probably going to remain the blessed tooling for Ember officially and I don't think there's anything wrong with that. generator-ember will continue to offer the best Ember scaffolding solution the Yeoman team are able to deliver but we'll be actively improving it based on the feedback from that community to hit parity with Ember-Tools and eventually supersede it as part of a greater collaborative effort.

Answer (score 1):

There's definitely an advantage of using EAK over yeoman's generator because of the reasons mentioned above. EAK is heavily worked on, its development is led by one of the core team members, it's been built with Ember in mind.

As to generators, there's a lot of work going on right now. [This](https://github.com/joliss/broccoli) is likely (it's not decided yet) to be used as a generator for EAK.